# Error - "Expression must have class type"

Tags: types, syntax-error

I am brand new to programming, and I don't understand the answers given to the other questions I've seen posted with similar questions.  Even the other questions are beyond my understanding at this point.

I'm trying to write a program that just outputs a few variations on cmath functions.  I've only learned primitive types and just started learning functions.

I don't understand why I'm getting an error saying the "Expression must have class type" with the code below.  I thought I declared the type to be a double, but it won't let me run the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double bill_total{375.18}, individual_bill{}, individual_bill_1{}, individual_bill_2{}, individual_bill_3{};
    int number_of_guests{ 5 };
    individual_bill = bill_total / number_of_guests;
    individual_bill_1 = individual_bill.floor();   //"individual_bill" getting error
    individual_bill_2 = individual_bill.round();   //"individual_bill" getting error
    individual_bill_3 = individual_bill.ceil();    //"individual_bill" getting error
    cout << "Bill 1: " << individual_bill_1 << endl
        << "Bill 2: " << individual_bill_2 << endl
        << "Bill 3: " << individual_bill_3 << endl;

}
```

Comment: (Aside: a good tip for Stack Overflow is to write succinctly, don't put any meta-material in your post, and leave out any complaints. If you get any criticism, say for your code or your question, bat it away constructively and with optimism, or take it as well meaning advice, even if it is a bit abrupt. Once you have got the knack for the right "mood" to use here, your posting will be plain-sailing thereafter. Good luck!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness,  `individual_bill` is a double.  `floor(individual_bill)` (ditto with ceil) is what is needed.